# Are fired faults released from memory if current autorelease pool is drained?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsautoreleasepool

I’m doing the iOS side of a sync routine, and I’m trying to keep a low memory profile.

The mom has these 2 entities:

- NSManagedObject Bar

  - to-many relationship to NSManagedObject Foo (“fooMembers”)
- NSManagedObject Foo

  - to-one relationship to NSManagedObject Bar
  - NSString attribute “masterObjectID”
  - many other relationships and attrs

I need to assemble a collection of all masterObjectID strings held by all the fooMembers of some bars that have been fetched. 
To do this, I iterate through the bars’ fooMembers -- which I assume fires the faults of all the foos -- and extract the masterObjectIDs, adding them to my collection.

The masterObjectID strings don’t take up too much memory, but the foos do.

**So my solution is to surround the foo-fault-firing iteration with an autorelease pool, retaining the masterObjectID strings but hoping that the foos will be released from memory when I drain that pool:**

```c
    NSMutableSet *smsetExistingMemberIDs = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[bar.fooMembers count]];

    NSAutoreleasePool *subpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // POOL

    for (Foo *foo in bar.fooMembers) 
        [smsetExistingMemberIDs addObject:[foo.masterObjectID retain]]; // retain the string so that it will survive the drain

    [subpool drain]; // DRAIN

    // work with smsetExistingMemberIDs...
```

**But am I right?** Does firing a fault actually put an NSManagedObject into the current autorelease pool? Or is my pool declaration and draining for naught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wienke,

The easiest answer is to create a separate managed object context (MOC) inside your autorelease pool. That way, when you are done with the loop, you can purge all of the items at one time. With a separate MOC, you will need to listen for changes but that is rather straightforward. Apple has a few examples that show private MOCs just for these kinds of actions.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it would be fairly easy to set up separate temporary contexts for this sort of thing, and if nullifying them afterward would clear all their object instances from memory, that sounds like the better way to go. But then I'm confused why you say "inside your autorelease pool." I'm assuming the subpool wouldn't be needed if I'm using the temporary-context scheme. Also, would you mind giving me a hint where to find those Apple examples? I looked at "Memory Management Using Core Data," but it lists none.

Comment: Oh, OK. The example is in "Efficiently Importing Data," which does suggest using both separate contexts and subpools. There's also that bit about re-faulting the objects by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`. If I did that after every single `foo` access, I'd release most of the memory right there. Which only leaves some confusion in my mind about why Apple docs always refer to faults being fired only when a change is made, when in fact upon testing they seem to be fired simply upon access...

Comment: Wienke, I find with CD that it is always best to manage your pools directly. CD can create so many objects that it can significantly affect your memory high water mark. `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` is most useful for breaking retain cycles. Due to the presence of inverse relations, they are incredibly easy to create in CD. You need to be careful with this method though. The standard advice is to call `-save:` before calling it. This ensures that you don't get any merge exceptions or overwrites of your properties. Andrew

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the extra clarification.